# fortran complex to real fftw issue

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw

I am currently working on a project where I need to implement a fourier transform and an inverse transform. I was testing a program I modified from an online example; the print or write commands are normally for debugging purposes:

```
  program testit
  INCLUDE 'fftw3.f'
  double complex out!, in
  real in
  parameter (N=100)
  dimension in(N), out(N)
  integer*8 p,p2
  integer i,j
  real x
  real fact
  write(*,*)"stuff in data"
  OPEN(UNIT=12, FILE="input.txt", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
  OPEN(UNIT=20, FILE="dftoutput.txt", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
  x=0
  in = 0
  do i=1,N/2
    in(i)=1
  enddo
  do i=1,N
  write(*,"(f10.2,1x,f10.2)")in(i)
  WRITE(12,*)real(in(i))
  enddo
  write(*,*)"create plans"
  call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(p ,N,in,out,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
  call dfftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(p2,N,in,out,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
  write(*,*)"do it"
  call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(p,in,out)
  do i=1,N
    write(*,"(f12.4,1x,f12.4)")out(i)
    WRITE(20,*)abs(out(i))
  enddo
  write(*,*)"undo it"
  call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(p2,in,out)
  fact=1.0/N
  do i=1,N
    write(*,)in(i)
    write(*,)out(i)
  enddo
  write(*,*)"clean up"
  call dfftw_destroy_plan(p,in,out)
  call dfftw_destroy_plan(p2,in,out)
  end program
```

The real to complex transformation works just fine. The inverse transformation gives wrong values and somehow it modifies both the in and out variables. I do not know what the problem is and I was not able to figure out any answers online. Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Chad W. Freer

Edit: I was also wondering if there is a similar function to fftshift() and ifftshift() from matlab in the fftw package.

Comment: You must describes how you get the wrong values, how do they look like and which values you expect.

Comment: According to the documentation of FFTW regarding [planner flags](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html#Planner-Flags) , >`FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` specifies that an out-of-place transform must not change its input array. This is ordinarily the default, except for c2r and hc2r (i.e. complex-to-real) transforms for which `FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT` is the default...

Answer (score 2):

There is a precision issue : on most computers, `real` refers to single precision 32bit floating point numbers. `real*8` can be used to specify double precision floating point numbers, to be consistent with `double complex` and `dfftw_...`.

For FFTW real to complex transform, if the size of the input is `N real*8`, then the [size of the output](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format.html#Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format) is `N/2+1 double complex`. Since the input is real, [coefficients of negative frequencies (higher than N/2+1) are conjugate of positive frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_real-input_DFT), and their computation is avoided.

According to the documentation of FFTW regarding [planner flags](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html#Planner-Flags) ,

> `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` specifies that an out-of-place transform must not change its input array. This is ordinarily the default, except for c2r and hc2r (i.e. complex-to-real) transforms for which `FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT` is the default...

If you wish to save the coefficients in the Fourier space `out`, either copy the array, or try to use `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT`. The first solution seems the best way to go if you have enough memory.

Order of arguments for FFTW functions is always `origin,destination`. As the backward transform is performed from `out` to `in` :

```
call dfftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(p2,N,out,in,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
...
call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(p2,out,in)
```

Here is a code based on yours, which performs forward and backward fft. It is compiled by `gfortran main.f90 -o main -lfftw3 -lm -Wall` :

```
program testit
INCLUDE 'fftw3.f'
double complex out!, in
real*8 in
parameter (N=100)
dimension in(N), out((N/2+1))
integer*8 p,p2
integer i
real x
real fact
write(*,*)"stuff in data"
OPEN(UNIT=12, FILE="input.txt", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
OPEN(UNIT=20, FILE="dftoutput.txt", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
x=0
in = 0
do i=1,N/2
  in(i)=1
enddo
do i=1,N
  write(*,"(f10.2,1x/)")in(i)
  WRITE(12,*)real(in(i))
enddo
write(*,*)"create plans"
call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(p ,N,in,out,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
call dfftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(p2,N,out,in,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
write(*,*)"do it"
call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(p,in,out)
do i=1,N/2+1
  write(*,"(f12.4,1x,f12.4/)")out(i)
  WRITE(20,*)abs(out(i))
enddo
write(*,*)"undo it"
call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(p2,out,in)
fact=1.0/N
write(*,*)"input back, except for scaling"
do i=1,N
  write(*,"(f10.2,1x)")in(i)
enddo
write(*,*)"output may be modified by c2r...except if FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT is set"
do i=1,N/2+1
  write(*,"(f10.2,1x,f10.2/)")out(i)
enddo
write(*,*)"clean up"
call dfftw_destroy_plan(p,in,out)
call dfftw_destroy_plan(p2,out,in)
end program
```

After the forward fft `in`->`out` and the backward fft `out`->`in` , `in` is identical to its initial value, except for a scale factor `N`.

Comment: Good catch. I cannot overstress that the modern Fortran bindings found in the include file `fftw3.f03` are much better and thanks to the explicit interfaces this error would be caught by the compiler.

Comment: Also I would add that there are single precision procedures available, should the OP want to keep it (as I often do).