# When using r2c and c2r FFTW in Fortran, are the forward and backward dimensions same?

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw

Blow is a main file

```
PROGRAM SPHEROID

USE nrtype
USE SUB_INFO
INCLUDE "/usr/local/include/fftw3.f"

INTEGER(I8B) :: plan_forward, plan_backward
INTEGER(I4B) :: i, t, int_N

REAL(DP) :: cth_i, sth_i, real_i, perturbation
REAL(DP) :: PolarEffect, dummy, x1, x2, x3

REAL(DP), DIMENSION(4096) :: dummy1, dummy2, gam, th, ph
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(4096) ::  k1, k2, k3, k4, l1, l2, l3, l4, f_in

COMPLEX(DPC), DIMENSION(2049) :: output1, output2, f_out

CHARACTER(1024) :: baseOutputFilename
CHARACTER(1024) :: outputFile, format_string

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

int_N = 4096

! File Open Section

format_string = '(I5.5)'

! Write the coodinates at t = 0

do i = 1, N
    real_i = real(i)
    gam(i) = 2d0*pi/real_N
    perturbation = 0.01d0*dsin(2d0*pi*real_i/real_N)
    ph(i) = 2d0*pi*real_i/real_N + perturbation
    th(i) = pi/3d0 + perturbation
end do

! Initialization Section for FFTW PLANS

call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(plan_forward, int_N, f_in, f_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
call dfftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(plan_backward, int_N, f_out, f_in, FFTW_ESTIMATE)

! Runge-Kutta 4th Order Method Section

do t = 1, Iter_N

    call integration(th, ph, gam, k1, l1)

    do i = 1, N
        dummy1(i) = th(i) + 0.5d0*dt*k1(i)
    end do
    do i = 1, N
        dummy2(i) = ph(i) + 0.5d0*dt*l1(i)
    end do

    call integration(dummy1, dummy2, gam, k2, l2)

    do i = 1, N
        dummy1(i) = th(i) + 0.5d0*dt*k2(i)
    end do
    do i = 1, N
        dummy2(i) = ph(i) + 0.5d0*dt*l2(i)
    end do

    call integration(dummy1, dummy2, gam, k3, l3)

    do i = 1, N
        dummy1(i) = th(i) + dt*k3(i)
    end do
    do i = 1, N
        dummy2(i) = ph(i) + dt*l3(i)
    end do

    call integration(dummy1, dummy2, gam, k4, l4)

    do i = 1, N

        cth_i = dcos(th(i))
        sth_i = dsin(th(i))
        PolarEffect = (nv-sv)*dsqrt(1d0+a*sth_i**2) + (nv+sv)*cth_i
        PolarEffect = PolarEffect/(sth_i**2)
        th(i) = th(i) + dt*(k1(i) + 2d0*k2(i) + 2d0*k3(i) + k4(i))/6d0
        ph(i) = ph(i) + dt*(l1(i) + 2d0*l2(i) + 2d0*l3(i) + l4(i))/6d0
        ph(i) = ph(i) + dt*0.25d0*PolarEffect/pi

    end do

!! Fourier Filtering Section

    call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan_forward, th, output1)

    do i = 1, N/2+1
       dummy = abs(output1(i))
        if (dummy.lt.threshhold) then
           output1(i) = dcmplx(0.0d0)
        end if
    end do

    call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan_backward, output1, th)

    do i = 1, N
       th(i) = th(i)/real_N
    end do

    call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan_forward, ph, output2)

    do i = 1, N/2+1
       dummy = abs(output2(i))
        if (dummy.lt.threshhold) then
           output2(i) = dcmplx(0.0d0)
        end if
    end do

    call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan_backward, output2, ph)

    do i = 1, N
       ph(i) = ph(i)/real_N
    end do

!! Data Writing Section

    write(baseOutputFilename, format_string) t
    outputFile = "xyz" // baseOutputFilename
    open(unit=7, file=outputFile)
    outputFile = "Fsptrm" // baseOutputFilename
    open(unit=8, file=outputFile)

    do i = 1, N
        x1 = dsin(th(i))*dcos(ph(i))
        x2 = dsin(th(i))*dsin(ph(i))
        x3 = dsqrt(1d0+a)*dcos(th(i))
        write(7,*) x1, x2, x3
    end do

    do i = 1, N/2+1
        write(8,*) abs(output1(i)), abs(output2(i))
    end do

    close(7)
    close(8)

    do i = 1, N/2+1
        output1(i) = dcmplx(0.0d0)
    end do

    do i = 1, N/2+1
        output2(i) = dcmplx(0.0d0)
    end do

end do

! Destroying Process for FFTW PLANS

call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward)
call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward)

END PROGRAM
```

Below is a subroutine file for integration

```
! We implemented Shelly's spectrally accurate convergence method

SUBROUTINE integration(in1,in2,in3,out1,out2)

USE nrtype
USE SUB_INFO

INTEGER(I4B) :: i, j
REAL(DP) :: th_i, th_j, gi, ph_i, ph_j, gam_j, v1, v2
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(N), INTENT(INOUT) :: in1, in2, in3, out1, out2
REAL(DP) :: ui, uj, part1, part2, gj, cph, sph
REAL(DP) :: denom, numer, temp

do i = 1, N
    out1(i) = 0d0
end do
do i = 1, N
    out2(i) = 0d0
end do

do i = 1, N

    th_i = in1(i)
    ph_i = in2(i)
    ui = dcos(th_i)
    part1 = dsqrt(1d0+a)/(dsqrt(-a)*ui+dsqrt(1d0+a-a*ui*ui))
    part1 = part1**(dsqrt(-a))
    part2 = (dsqrt(1d0+a-a*ui*ui)+ui)/(dsqrt(1d0+a-a*ui*ui)-ui)
    part2 = dsqrt(part2)

    gi = dsqrt(1d0-ui*ui)*part1*part2

    do j = 1, N

        if (mod(i+j,2).eq.1) then

            th_j = in1(j)
            ph_j = in2(j)
            gam_j = in3(j)

            uj = dcos(th_j)
            part1 = dsqrt(1d0+a)/(dsqrt(-a)*uj+dsqrt(1d0+a-a*uj*uj))
            part1 = part1**(dsqrt(-a))
            part2 = (dsqrt(1d0+a-a*uj*uj)+uj)/(dsqrt(1d0+a-a*uj*uj)-uj)
            part2 = dsqrt(part2)

            gj = dsqrt(1d0-ui*ui)*part1*part2

            cph = dcos(ph_i-ph_j)
            sph = dsin(ph_i-ph_j)

            numer = dsqrt(1d0-uj*uj)*sph
            denom = (gj/gi*(1d0-ui*ui) + gi/gj*(1d0-uj*uj))*0.5d0
            denom = denom - dsqrt((1d0-ui*ui)*(1d0-uj*uj))*cph
            denom = denom + krasny_delta
            v1 = -0.25d0*gam_j*numer/denom/pi

            temp = dsqrt(1d0+(1d0-ui*ui)*a)
            numer = -(gj/gi)*(temp+ui)
            numer = numer + (gi/gj)*((1d0-uj*uj)/(1d0-ui*ui))*(temp-ui)
            numer = numer + 2d0*ui*dsqrt((1d0-uj*uj)/(1d0-ui*ui))*cph
            numer = 0.5d0*numer
            v2 = -0.25d0*gam_j*numer/denom/pi

            out1(i) = out1(i) + 2d0*v1
            out2(i) = out2(i) + 2d0*v2

        end if

    end do

end do

END
```

Below is a module file

```
module nrtype
Implicit none
!integer
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I8B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(20)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I4B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I2B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I1B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(2)
!real
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SP = KIND(1.0)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0D0)
!complex
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SPC = KIND((1.0,1.0))
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DPC = KIND((1.0D0,1.0D0))
!defualt logical
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: LGT = KIND(.true.)
!mathematical constants
REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_dp
!derived data type s for sparse matrices,single and double precision
!User-Defined Constants
INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: N = 4096, Iter_N = 20000
REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: real_N = 4096d0
REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: a = -0.1d0, dt = 0.001d0, krasny_delta = 0.01d0
REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: nv = 0d0, sv = 0d0, threshhold = 0.00000000001d0
!N : The Number of Point Vortices, Iter_N * dt = Total time, dt : Time Step
!krasny_delta : Smoothing Parameter introduced by R.Krasny
!nv : Northern Vortex Strength, sv : Southern Vortex Strength
!a : The Eccentricity in the direction of z , threshhold : Filtering Threshhold
end module nrtype
```

Below is a subroutine info file

```
MODULE SUB_INFO

INTERFACE
  SUBROUTINE integration(in1,in2,in3,out1,out2)
  USE nrtype
  INTEGER(I4B) :: i, j
  REAL(DP) :: th_i, th_j, gi, ph_i, ph_j, gam_j, v1, v2
  REAL(DP), DIMENSION(N), INTENT(INOUT) :: in1, in2, in3, out1, out2
  REAL(DP) :: ui, uj, part1, part2, gj, cph, sph
  REAL(DP) :: denom, numer, temp
  END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE

END MODULE
```

I compiled them using the below command

```
gfortran -o p0 -fbounds-check nrtype.f90 spheroid_sub_info.f90 spheroid_sub_integration.f90 spheroid_main.f90 -lfftw3 -lm -Wall -pedantic -pg
```

nohup ./p0 &

Note that 2049 = 4096 / 2 + 1

When making plan_backward, isn't it correct that we use 2049 instead of 4096 since the dimension of output is 2049?

But when I do that, it blows up. (Blowing up means NAN error)

If I use 4096 in making plan_backward, Everything is fine except that some Fourier coefficients are abnormally big which should not happen.

Please help me use FFTW in Fortran correctly. This issue has discouraged me for a long time.

Comment: I believe my code is quite minimal. and also I confirmed that this code works well verified by the plotted result xyz-coordinates. But Fourier coefficients are abnormal. So I suspect that there is a problem in using FFTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue may be that `dfftw_execute_dft_c2r` can destroy the content of the input array, as described in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322026/fortran-complex-to-real-fftw-issue?rq=1). The key excerpt is

> `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` specifies that an out-of-place transform must not change its input array. This is ordinarily the default, except for c2r and hc2r (i.e. complex-to-real) transforms for which `FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT`is the default...

We can verify this, for example, by modifying the sample code by @VladimirF such that it saves `data_out` to `data_save` right after the first FFT(r2c) call, and then calculating their difference after the second FFT (c2r) call. So, in the case of OP's code, it  seems safer to save `output1` and `output2` to different arrays before entering the second FFT (c2r).

Comment: Even if I solved it without such knowledge, I really appreciate your answer. It truly helped me understand the phenomenon.

Comment: @Sah-mooKim Hi, I didn't know this exceptional behavior either because I had never used complex-to-real FFT before. I believe the FFTW website should emphasize this much more clearly...

Answer (score 2):

First, although you claim your example is minimal, it is still pretty large, I have no time to study it.

But I updated my gist code https://gist.github.com/LadaF/73eb430682ef527eea9972ceb96116c5 to show also the backward transform and to answer the title question about the transform dimensions.

The logical size of the transform is the size of the real array ([Real-data DFT Array Format](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format.html#Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format)) but the complex part is smaller due to inherent symmetries.

But when you make first r2c transform from real array of size `n` to complex array of size `n/2+1`. and then an opposite transform back, the real array should be again of size `n`.

This is my minimal example from the gist:

```
module FFTW3
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  include "fftw3.f03"
end module

    use FFTW3
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: n = 100

    real(c_double), allocatable :: data_in(:)
    complex(c_double_complex), allocatable :: data_out(:)
    type(c_ptr) :: planf, planb

    allocate(data_in(n))
    allocate(data_out(n/2+1))

    call random_number(data_in)

    planf = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(size(data_in), data_in, data_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE+FFTW_UNALIGNED)
    planb = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(size(data_in), data_out, data_in, FFTW_ESTIMATE+FFTW_UNALIGNED)

    print *, "real input:", real(data_in)

    call fftw_execute_dft_r2c(planf, data_in, data_out)

    print *, "result real part:", real(data_out)

    print *, "result imaginary part:", aimag(data_out)

    call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(planb, data_out, data_in)

    print *, "real output:", real(data_in)/n

    call fftw_destroy_plan(planf)
    call fftw_destroy_plan(planb)
end
```

Note that I am using the modern Fortran interface. I don't like using the old one.

Comment: I solved my problem. After inverse FFT, complex fourier variables changed. It caused my problem. But I don't know why such an error happens...