# FFTW in Fortran result contains only zeros

Tags: fortran, fft, gfortran, fftw

I have been trying to write a simple program to perform an fft on a 1D input array using fftw3. Here I am using a seismogram as an input. The output array is, however, coming out to contain only zeroes.

I know that the input is correct as I have tried doing the fft of the same input file in MATLAB as well, which gives correct results. There is no compilation error. I am using f95 to compile this, however, gfortran was also giving pretty much the same results. Here is the code that I wrote:-

```
program fft

    use functions
    implicit none
    include 'fftw3.f90'
    integer nl,row,col
    double precision, allocatable :: data(:,:),time(:),amplitude(:)
    double complex, allocatable :: out(:)
    integer*8 plan


    open(1,file='test-seismogram.xy')
    nl=nlines(1,'test-seismogram.xy')
    allocate(data(nl,2))
    allocate(time(nl))
    allocate(amplitude(nl))
    allocate(out(nl/2+1))
    do row = 1,nl
        read(1,*,end=101) data(row,1),data(row,2)
        amplitude(row)=data(row,2)
    end do
    101 close(1)


    call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(plan,nl,amplitude,out,FFTW_R2HC,FFTW_PATIENT)
    call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan, amplitude, out)
    call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan)


    do row=1,(nl/2+1)
        print *,out(row)
    end do


    deallocate(data)
    deallocate(amplitude)
    deallocate(time)
    deallocate(out)
end program fft
```

The `nlines()` function is a function which is used to calculate the number of lines in a file, and it works correctly. It is defined in the module called functions.

This program pretty much tries to follow the example at http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Fortran-Examples.html

There might just be a very simple logical error that I am making, but I am seriously unable to figure out what is going wrong here. Any pointers would be very helpful.

This is pretty much how the whole output looks like:-

```
           .
           .
           .
           (0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
           (0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
           (0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
           (0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
           (0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
           .
           .
           .
```

My doubt is directly regarding fftw, since there is a tag for fftw on SO, so I hope this question is not off topic

Comment: In 2018 I strongly recommend using the modern (Fortran 2003) interface. Did you print the input data as well? Is the data read from the file correctly? I even more strongly recommend to use unit numbers larger than 1 and `action="read", status="old"`.

Comment: Yes, I did print the input data, and it is being read correctly. And about modern Fortran, since most of the code I have in my lab is written in legacy Fortran, I had to learn even some f77 syntax. However, I am slowly getting used to the modern interface.

Comment: I will keep what you recommended in mind. Thank you. However, I don't think that is the solution to this problem I think?

Comment: Just comparing with the linked page, is FFTW_R2HC necessary? (it is not present in the linked page)

Comment: FFTW_R2HC is not necessary as such, it just tells the subroutine to do a forward Fourier transform. This is also present in the documentation, albeit on some different page which I don't remember. It is however not the source of the problem. The result is coming out to be same with or without it

Comment: When calling dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(), are input and output arrays probably overwritten to measure the performance? (according to [this page](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html)). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322026/fortran-complex-to-real-fftw-issue?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885526/when-using-r2c-and-c2r-fftw-in-fortran-are-the-forward-and-backward-dimensions) page may also be relevant (later)

Comment: @roygvib is right - you're planning with the same data you intend to use later, but planning typically destroys the data. If you don't really care about speed, you can use `FFTW_ESTIMATE` as the planning flag, and then the data will not be overwritten. Otherwise, plan before reading your data.

Comment: Yes that was the problem apparently. I actually do care about speed, so I can just use different arrays for the planning right? Thank you @roygvib

Comment: And thank you @Ross. If any one of you is willing to write an answer, I will be happy to accept it

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita I would appreciate it if you add an answer in any form (e.g. a short copy from the above linked page). I believe it would also be really nice if we can learn how the actual results/timing change depending on FFTW_ESTIMATE/MEASURE/PATIENT etc (just for interest...)

Comment: i'm sure this is unrelated but you have a variable integer*8 plan.  the variable plan is not set to any value.

Comment: @jmh The plan subroutine sets it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments first by @roygvib and @Ross, the plan subroutines overwrite the input arrays because they try the transform many times with different parameters. I will add some practical use considerations.

You claim you do care about performance. Then there are two possibilities:

1. You do the transform *only once* as you show in your code. Then there is no point to use `FFTW_MEASURE`. The planning subroutine is **many times slower** than actual plan execute subroutine. Use `FFTW_ESTIMATE` and it will be much faster.

> FFTW_MEASURE tells FFTW to find an optimized plan **by actually
> computing several FFTs** and measuring their execution time. Depending
> on your machine, this can **take some time** (often a few seconds).
> FFTW_MEASURE is the default planning option.
>
> FFTW_ESTIMATE specifies that, instead of actual measurements of
> different algorithms, a simple heuristic is used to pick a (probably
> sub-optimal) plan **quickly**. With this flag, the **input/output arrays are
> not overwritten** during planning.

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html

2. You do the same transform *many times* for different data. Then you must do the planning **only once** before the first transform and than re-use the plan. Just make the plan first and only then you fill the array with the first input data. Making the plan before every transport would make the program extremely slow.